# Browser randomly opens router login requester instead of webpage

Tags: router, hijack

I don't understand why this is happening..3 or 4 times a day when I'm browsing the web I'll click a link in my bookmarks and instead of going to the webpage a requester comes up asking for my router login.  If I escape out of that I get a Forbidden Access denial.  Just now this kept happening with Google News (I'm using Firefox Nightly on a Mac 10.8.3) and while I could browse to another website ok, every try to open news.google.com got the requester for the router.  The router is a Netgear router set up as a bridge that wirelessly connects to a Cisco wireless router cabled to the cable modem.  What could be going on?  This has been happening for a couple of months and I can't figure out what the problem is.  I just reset Firefox and it's still happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how long does it happen for? try pinging www.google.com when it happens. maybe you are losing internet access, during that time. so maybe your bridge or router is failing. is your modem connected publicly no NAT, not taking an IP, and just passing on the public ip. Then your cisco wireless router doing NAT, and your netgear just as a bridge, and perhaps more relevantly, is your router login is that from the cisco router?